# Meaning of ヘイコラ

Tags: words

I found this sentence in a book:

> 「当時のわしは、人間が憎かったんじゃ。多くの仲間たちが、ドワーフというだけで虐げられ、人間のせいで故郷を追われたのに、生きるために人間に**ヘイコラ**せねばならん。その『憎しみ』が、わしの目を曇らせたんじゃ」

The character is speaking about a test he took in the past, were he failed because he assumed the best sword could have been made by a human, since dwarves were (at least in his eyes) better blacksmiths.

I understand most of the sentence, but I cannot understand ヘイコラ; I tried to parse it in any way I could think of, but I found no useful words or meaning.

As far as I understand, the character is saying "At the time I hated humans. Many fellow dwarves were oppressed just because they were dwarves and were driven off their land by humans", then something about humans and "in order to live" (生きるために), then "That hate clouded my eyes". But I have no idea about the ヘイコラ part

Comment: Did you look up へいこら in a dictionary?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie yes, several of them, bilingual; but now that you mentioned it I tried a monolingual - which I didn't think of before - and I found this https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%89, which makes sense, so I guess it was an oversight to not think about checking it first.

Comment: Fun fact: ひーこら also exists

Comment: @Mauro Maybe you could self-answer your question then?

Comment: 明鏡国語辞典, 3rd ed., says `へつらって、ぺこぺこ頭をさげるさま。「上役にへいこらする」`

Comment: I guess 憎かったんじゃん should've been 憎かったんじゃ, and 人間おせい → 人間のせい?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to a comment from Darius Jahandarie I found it's a word not listed on bilingual dictionaries, but it can be found for example [here](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B8%E3%81%84%E3%81%93%E3%82%89):

> 相手の機嫌をとろうとして、やたらに頭を下げたり言いなりになったりするさま。「上役に—する」

In the comments, naruto quotes a definition from 明鏡国語辞典, which confirms this is it:

> へつらって、ぺこぺこ頭をさげるさま。「上役にへいこらする」